# Shell script to accept string from command line and display list of files containing the string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, filesystems

How to write a shell script that will search a list of files under a directory(or subdirectories) for a given string from the *command line* and display all files that contain the string.

Answer (score 2):

try this, if it gives you what you want:

```
grep -rl "string" **/*
```

Comment: what is your input? filename? or a bunch of text? what do you want to do? in Question you want to do recursive grep and list the filename, now it was changed or not?

Comment: input is a string and the script must go through a folder and display the files that contain the string

Comment: if you have `s=string` then `grep -rl "$s" **/*`

Answer (score 0):

Basic example:

```
#!/bin/sh

STRING=$1
DIR=$2

find $DIR -type f -exec grep -l $STRING {} \;
```

Fixing up to handle whitespace etc is left as an exercize for the student.

I've named the script "findfile.sh" and run it with first argument = the string to find, second = the directory to look in. LIke this:

```
[jenny@ryo-ohki:tmp]$ ./findstring.sh lyskom /home/jenny/src/elisp
/home/jenny/src/elisp/lyskom-elisp-client-all-0.48/README
/home/jenny/src/elisp/lyskom-elisp-client-all-0.48/lyskom-all-0.48.el
/home/jenny/src/elisp/lyskom-elisp-client-all-0.48/lyskom-all-0.48.elc
/home/jenny/src/elisp/lyskom-elisp-client-all-0.48/NEWS-0.48
/home/jenny/src/elisp/lyskom-all-0.48.elc
/home/jenny/src/elisp/lyskom-swedish-0.48.elc
/home/jenny/src/elisp/lyskom.elc
```

As you can see it lists every fil containing the word "lyskom" in the directory /home/jenny/src/elisp/ and its subdirectories.

Comment: @user2115365 `myscript "searchstring" /tmp` will list all files in /tmp (and subdirectories) that contain "searchstring"

Answer (score 0):

This shell script displays all the files containing the specified string

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -l "$1" *
```

you can save it as find_util.sh and do

```
chmod a+x find_util.sh

./find_util.sh search
```

if you want it to search sub directories also you can change it as

```
#!/bin/bash
grep -lr "$1" *
```